# Converting string to datetime in Python using strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert the following String to datetime object in Python.

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Sat, 26 Nov 2016 15:17:00 +0000', '%a, %b %d %Y %H:%c %z')
```

I get the following error,

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 342, in _strptime
    format_regex = _TimeRE_cache.compile(format)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 272, in compile
    return re_compile(self.pattern(format), IGNORECASE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 234, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 813, in _parse
    raise source.error(err.msg, len(name) + 1) from None
re.error: redefinition of group name 'a' as group 6; was group 1 at position 185
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you right off hand, but try out `dateutil.parser` like so: `from dateutil.parser import parse; _date = parse('Sat, 26 Nov 2016 15:17:00 +0000')`

Comment: When I run your piece of code I get the error `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'`. Any chance that you  have mistaken `datetime` instead of `time` module? With the second I get that same mentioned error

Comment: The docs have a good explanation of the directives and what they're used for. `'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'` is what you should have been using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but there were a few errors in [the directives](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) you were using. Try:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Sat, 26 Nov 2016 15:17:00 +0000', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')

>>> datetime_object
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 26, 15, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 2):

`%c` is defined as [`Locale’s appropriate date and time representation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).
This means that `%c` is in fact a macro for the current locale's format string and thus is meant to be used by itself.

In the case of en_US, your format string expands to
`'%a, %b %d %Y %H:%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z'`
As you can see, `%a` is in position 1 as well as position 6.

Writing correct format strings requires quite a bit of careful book-keeping.