# pysrt: get time in milliseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to get the start and  end time of a subtitle file in milliseconds:

```
SIMPLE_FILE = """
1
00:00:03,010 --> 00:00:33,400
cette matrice-là <i>E<sub>t</sub>·…·E<sub>1</sub>A</i> possède une ligne

2
00:01:00,000 --> 00:02:31,020
there was a SubRip file
with two subtitles.
"""
with open("subtitles.srt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as fp:fp.write(SIMPLE_FILE)
```

I load the subtitle file using [pysrt](https://github.com/byroot/pysrt):

```
import pysrt
sub = pysrt.open("subtitles.srt")
# Start and End time
start = sub[0].start.to_time()
end = sub[0].end.to_time()

print(start)
print(end)
```

> 00:00:03.010000
>
> 00:00:33.400000

As you can see I am getting a Hour:Minutes:Seconds.Millisecond format back. Now, my question is: how can I convert this into milliseconds?

### Edit

I checked the type:

```
type(start)
```

> datetime.time

### Edit 2

Based on [Converting string to datetime in Python using strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730311/converting-string-to-datetime-in-python-using-strptime)

I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_obj = datetime.strptime(str(start),
                           '%H:%M:%S.%f')
millisec = dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000

print(millisec)
```

I get:

> ---
>
> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 3 dt_obj = datetime.strptime(str(start),
> 4                            '%H:%M:%S.%f')
> ----> 5 millisec = dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000
> 6
> 7 print(millisec)
>
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to parse `start`, because it already is a `time` object. Just access its properties. See [`datetime.time` specs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects).

You should be able to access:

```
start.hour
start.minute
start.second
start.microsecond
```

Comment: So, I would do: `milliseconds = start.hour*3600000 + start.minute*60000 + start.second*1000 + start.microsecond*0.001` , right ?

Comment: @henry yes, i'd do that, or `((start.hour * 60 + start.minute) * 60 + start.second) * 1000 + start.microsecond`

Comment: Quick question: why do you just add mircoseconds ? wouldn't it have to be 0.001*microseconds to get milliseconds ?